# Checking if an R function argument is an NA causes a problem when applied to vectors

Tags: r, function

I created a function to turn pounds, shillings and pence into a decimal price that starts by checking if the argument is NA or an empty character string. It works perfectly with a single character string, but gives me an error if I apply it to a character vector (I am using R 4.2.1):

```
psp_to_decimal <- function(x){
  # Converts pounds shillings and pence to a decimal price
  psp <- strsplit(x, " ")[[1]]

  if(is.na(x) | trimws(x) == ""){
    decimal_price <- NA

  } else {
    decimal_price <- 0
    if(grepl("£", psp[1], fixed = TRUE)) {
      pounds <- gsub("£", "", psp[1])
      decimal_price <- decimal_price + as.numeric(pounds)
      psp <- psp[-1]
    }
    
    if(length(psp)>0 && grepl("s", psp[1], fixed = TRUE)) {
      shillings <- gsub("s", "", psp[1])
      decimal_price <- decimal_price + as.numeric(shillings) / 20
      psp <- psp[-1]
    }
  
    if(length(psp)>0 && grepl("d", psp[1], fixed = TRUE)) {
      pence <- gsub("d", "", psp[1])
      decimal_price <- decimal_price + as.numeric(pence) / 240
    }
  }
  writeLines(c("decimal price", decimal_price))
  return(decimal_price)
}
```

I create a vector to test it:

```
x <- c("£7 2s 10d", "£12 5s 1d", "2s 4d")
```

This works fine if I type

```
> psp_to_decimal(x[1])
[1] 7.114166
```

but chokes if I type

```
> psp_to_decimal(x)
Error in if (is.na(x) | trimws(x) == "") { : the condition has length > 1
```

Clearly is.na() and trimws() are apply themselves to the entire vector, and not to each item  individually. How do I get psp_to_decimal_test to convert each item in x to a decimal?

Many thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can use the function exactly the way it is in the question, by using `sapply` as follows:

```
> x <- c("£7 2s 10d", "£12 5s 1d", "2s 4d")
> sapply(x,psp_to_decimal)
decimal price
7.14166666666667
decimal price
12.2541666666667
decimal price
0.116666666666667
 £7 2s 10d  £12 5s 1d      2s 4d 
 7.1416667 12.2541667  0.1166667
```

But I assume it's preferred to avoid this. So, here's an adaptation of your function to work for vectors as well.

```
psp_to_decimal <- function(x){
  # Converts pounds shillings and pence to a decimal price
  psp <- strsplit(x, " ")
  
  decimal_price <- sapply(seq(psp), function(i) {
    psp_temp <- psp[[i]]
    if(is.na(x[i]) | trimws(x[i]) == ""){
      decimal_price <- NA
    } else {
      decimal_price <- 0
      if(grepl("£", psp_temp[1], fixed = TRUE)) {
        pounds <- gsub("£", "", psp_temp[1])
        decimal_price <- decimal_price + as.numeric(pounds)
        psp_temp <- psp_temp[-1]
      }
      
      if(length(psp_temp)>0 && grepl("s", psp_temp[1], fixed = TRUE)) {
        shillings <- gsub("s", "", psp_temp[1])
        decimal_price <- decimal_price + as.numeric(shillings) / 20
        psp_temp <- psp_temp[-1]
      }
      
      if(length(psp_temp)>0 && grepl("d", psp_temp[1], fixed = TRUE)) {
        pence <- gsub("d", "", psp_temp[1])
        decimal_price <- decimal_price + as.numeric(pence) / 240
      }
    }
    writeLines(c("decimal price", decimal_price))
    return(decimal_price)
  })
  
  return(decimal_price)
}
```

The function is very slightly changed to loop through `x`, so it can produce results for all values of the vector.

Comment: Thank you for both your solutions. Given that `sapply` is simpler, that's the way I'll go, but to be honest, I don't understand why you need to loop within psp_to_decimal, as the function works correctly with scalars / vectors of length 1. It's bothersome to see it not repeatedly apply itself to every element of the input vector just as sapply (and most functions) do.  I would be very appreciative if you could explain in simple terms what is it about my function that makes it behave in this way with vectors. It must be something related to the error checking, but what is that something?